# Is it possible to shape and queue on a switched port in a cisco 4506-E?

Tags: cisco, qos

**Background**

I have a cisco 4506-E with a sup 7L-E running IOS-XE 03.04.03.SG.  The switch is connected to a 150 Mbps circuit via 1 Gbps ethernet port.  The port is configured as a switched access port.  There is a policy-map applied to shape the port to 150 Mbps as follows:

`policy-map foo

  class class-default

    shape average 150000000`

There is voip and video running over the circuit.  In addition to shaping i'd like to make use of hardware output queues, especially the priority queue for voip.  The ideal case would be to apply the "auto qos trust" settings in addition to the shaping.

**Question**

Is it possible to configure both shaping and queueing on a switched port such that the shaping happens first and then the queueing?  Please provide a simple example policy-map.

Comment: FYI, Cat4500 supervisors do not support shaping directly on the ports on the Supervisor LC itself.

Comment: Good to know.  In this case the port is on a WS-X4748-UPOE+E, not on the sup.  shaping seems to work - I just need queueing to work as well.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

This should be possible by using Hierarchical Queueing Framework (HQF).

The parent policy-map will do the shaping and the child policy-map will do the queueing. Configuration would look something like this:

```
class-map CM_VOICE
 match dscp ef
!
class CM_VIDEO
 match dscp cs4
!
policy-map PM_CHILD
 class CM_VOICE
  priority
  police percent 30
 !
 class CM_VIDEO
  bandwidth percent 50
!
policy-map PM_PARENT
 class class-default
  shape average 150000000
  service-policy PM_CHILD
!
```

Obviously replace matching with your own values, ACLs etc.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to define a service-policy from within a policy-map as you have done in your example.  service-policy isn't a valid option within config-pmap-c

Comment: Sorry for that. I was sure I had seen this configured on a 4500 before. Looking through the configuration guide I can't find any examples with HQF.

Comment: I think HQF may not be supported.  I think your config above is valid for routers and some line cards on 6500s but not on the 4500.